# Error downloading Lumen via Composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, lumen, lumen-5.2

I just updated my Laravel version to 5.2 as well as updating my composer. Then when I tried to install Lumen via composer, I am getting an error of:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/lumen-installer v1.0.1
>       - Conclusion: remove symfony/process v3.0.0
>       - Installation request for laravel/lumen-installer ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/lumen-installer[v1.0.0, v1.0.1].
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v3.0.0
>       - laravel/lumen-installer v1.0.0 requires symfony/process ~2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11,
>   v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18,
>   v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25,
>   v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32,
>   v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8,
>   v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5,
>   v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11,
>   v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8,
>   v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.2, v2.6.3,
>   v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1,
>   v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.8.0].
>
> - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.0, v3.0.0].
> - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.1, v3.0.0].
> - ...
> - Installation request for symfony/process == 3.0.0.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v3.0.0].
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

I just ran this command on my command line base on what is stated on the [documentation](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/installation):

```
composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer=~1.0"
```

Comment: What php version do you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that you have already added a package globally that used
`symfony/process ~3.0.0` but Lumen installer requires `symfony/process ~2.3` so composer cannot install both.

You can either try to resolve this yourself by removing that package and installing Lumen installer globally, add the installer to your working directory (i.e. leave out the `global` keyword and you should be able to use it in that directory) or Lumen provides a way to install itself directly, by simply running:

`composer create-project laravel/lumen YourProjectName --prefer-dist`

in your installation directory.

Answer (score 3):

Checking out the latest commits for lumen installer https://github.com/laravel/lumen-installer. It appears there was a recent fix to the installers dependencies (i.e. symfony/process ~2.3|~3.0).

If you're keen to use the installer sooner rather than later get the dev-master version
`composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer=dev-master"` until there is an official release. Otherwise you can wait until the fix is properly released.